# Get number of records in table before given entry / get record absolute ID

Tags: mongodb

I know the _id (ObjectID) of some entry; is there any way to get its relative position from the table start / number of records before it, *without writing any code*?

*(the stuff was required for debugging some application which ha*d* messy 'no deletions' policy along with incremental record numbers and in-memory collections)*

**UPD**: still looking for native way to do such things, but here's some perl sweets:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;
use strict;
my $ppl = MongoDB::Connection->new(username=>"root", password=>"toor")->webapp->users->find();

my $c = 0;
while (my $user = $ppl->next) {
    $c++;
    print "$user->{_id} $c\n" if ( $user->{'_id'} =~/4...6|4...5/);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no information in an ObjectID that you can reliably use to know how many older documents are in the same collection. The "inc" part of the ObjectId comes close but exact values depend on driver implementation (and can even be random) and would require all writes to come from the same machine to a mongod that's managing a single collection.

TL;DR : No

Comment: but what about information in a queryset? Mongo starts looking for entries, mongo knows total count for them, what makes it unable to find a number of entries processed before the one distinct was found?

Comment: That's not how MongoDB works (or most other databases) work. It is not guaranteed to walk the entire candidate set in order of insertion time since that might not be the most obvious/efficient query plan. And that's ignoring the fact that most queries (and definitely ones based on _id) use indexes which are specifically designed to avoid having to scan candidate documents in order. Even the "nscanned" field that is returned by an explain() operation is not necessarily a reflection of how many "older" documents are in the collection compared to the first document that matched the query